# Github API incomplete/forever cached JSON for orgs/eea/repos

Tags: json, git, api, caching, github

I have an issue with github API v3 as it seems to forever cache or somehow drop some repositories within this JSON:

https://api.github.com/orgs/eea/repos

Look for eea.soercontent or eea.package. They're missing even if they are displayed here:

https://github.com/eea/

Any clue? Is there a way to invalidate this cache, if any?

Answer (score 1):

On 08/27/2013 06:48 PM, James Dennes (GitHub Staff) wrote:

> Hey Alin,
>
> Thanks for getting in touch – it looks like you're getting Trolled By Pagination™.
>
> You'll need to request the next page of results to see those repositories. The Link header of the response contains the pagination details:
>
> Link:https://api.github.com/organizations/1176627/repos?page=2; rel="next", https://api.github.com/organizations/1176627/repos?page=2; rel="last"
>
> All the details on pagination are here:
>
> http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination
>
> I hope that helps.
>
> Cheers,
>   James